# Можно ли кастить template<A> к template<B> если B родитель A?

Tags: c#, ооп, generics, интерфейс

Есть базовый класс и у него есть наследник. И есть дженерик ограниченный базовым классом. Также есть интерфейсы реализуемые двумя разными классами.
Во время реализации второго интерфейса в строчке:

```
    return BuilderResource.GetPath( LoadedResources );
```

Происходит ошибка:

> Compilation error (line 47, col 35): Argument 1: cannot convert from
>   'ResourceReference' to 'ResourceReference'

Что нужно сделать чтобы он нормально конвертировал? Задача не исправить тип в `BuilderInfo` а именно конвертировать.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var a = new BuilderComponent<string>("Hi!");
        a.Write();
    }
}

public class GameComponent { }

public class SceneObject : GameComponent { }

public class ResourceReference<T> where T : GameComponent {}

public interface IBuilderResource {  ResourceReference<GameComponent> GetPath ( ResourceReference<GameComponent> res);  }

public class BuilderComponent<T> : IBuilderResource{

    T str;

    public BuilderComponent(T str) { this.str = str;    }

    public void Write()  { Console.WriteLine(str);  }

    public ResourceReference<GameComponent> GetPath ( ResourceReference<GameComponent> res) { return res;   }
}



public interface IBuilderViewInfo { ResourceReference<SceneObject> GetPath(); }

public class BuilderInfo : IBuilderViewInfo {

    protected readonly ResourceReference<SceneObject> LoadedResources;
    protected readonly IBuilderResource BuilderResource;

    public BuilderInfo( ResourceReference<SceneObject> loadedResources, IBuilderResource builderResource)
    {
        LoadedResources = loadedResources;
        BuilderResource = builderResource;
    }

    public ResourceReference<SceneObject> GetPath()  {  
        return BuilderResource.GetPath( LoadedResources );  
    }
}
```

Для эксперимента тестовый образец:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/oCqSlq

Comment: А зачем? это что генерация страниц, взлом, или зачем такие сложности? Не совсем понятно что делает программа.

Comment: Можете использовать `Convert.ChangeType` а тип получить по token, но скорее всего таким образом ошибка перейдёт с ошибки компиляции в ошибку runtime.

Comment: А так ? `return (ResourceReference)BuilderResource.GetPath( LoadedResources );`

Comment: А может немного с наследованием как то можно более элегантно пофиксить этот вопрос? Тут не прямо в лоб конвертировать нужно а как просто может логическую ошибку в коде исправить но не трогать типы.

Comment: выдает  `Argument 1: cannot convert from 'ResourceReference<SceneObject>' to 'ResourceReference<GameComponent>' ` там в песочнице по ссылке внизу

Comment: Такую конвертацию сделать скорее всего нельзя. Прийдётся вам разворачивать и пересворачивать template

Comment: Ну вот а почему? там же у `SceneObject` есть базовый класс `GameComponent` и он же является ограничителем типа у дженерика `ResourceReference`?

Comment: Напишите в заголовке вопроса, "можно ли кастить template<A> к template<B> если B родитель A." мне конкретно такие действия не приходилось делать. Или более понятный заголовок

Comment: Попробуйте кастить к интерфейсу, возможно к интерфейсу разрешит.

Comment: Может вместо `public ResourceReference<SceneObject> GetPath()` вам надо написать так:  `public ResourceReference<T> GetPath()` и будет как надо? Просто иногда непонятно что в `<>` писать. Шаблоны созданы как раз что б тип везде подставить, а T - подстановка.

Comment: Тогда нужно делать этот класс дженериком что потянет за собой его изменение везде по коду.

Comment: Без замены на интерфейсы - не заработает - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733346/why-isnt-there-generic-variance-for-classes-in-c-sharp-4-0/2734070#2734070

Comment: А что имеется в виду под заменой на интерфейсы в моем случае ?

Comment: @Alex нет возможности проверить вживую, но скорее всего `public interface IResourceReference<out T>` и дополнительный каст в GetPath  - `(IResourceReference<SceneObject>)BuilderResource.GetPath(LoadedResources);`

Comment: в IResourceReference переименовывать необязательно, достаточно поменять на интерфейс

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я думаю подобный каст невозможен. Объясню почему я так считаю. Когда мы создаем объекты типов Tempalte и Tempalte, то компилятор генерирует эти два типа, которых раньше не было, что-то вроде Template<[A]> и Template<[B]>. Эти типы начинают реально существовать, как если бы в ручную описали такие типы и затем скомпилировали. А ваш обобщенный тип Template служит шаблоном для создания этих типов. Плохая новость в том, что компилятор не отслеживает наследование параметров A и B при генерации новых типов, поэтому между типами Template и Tempalte неявное приведение невозможно. Хорошая новость в том, что эти новые типы наследуют типу Objeсе как и любой другой тип в C# (Template<[A]>: Object, Template<[B]>: Object). Поэтому мы можем делать сложное приведение через object

```
public ResourceReference<SceneObject> GetPath()  {  
    var gameComponent = BuilderResource.GetPath( (LoadedResources as object) as ResourceReference<GameComponent> );  
    return (gameComponent as object) as ResourceReference<SceneObject>;
}
```